# scanf("%c") automatically reads 10

Tags: c, scanf

```
void main() 
{ 
    int cnt=1; 
    char i; 
    while(cnt<4) 
    {
        printf("\nenter the character"); 
        scanf("%c",&i); 
        if(i>64 && i<91) 
            printf("\ncharacter is entered"); 
        else 
            printf("\nnumber is entered"); 
        cnt++; 
    }
}
```

In the above program, during the second iteration, `i` automatically takes 10. So the control goes to `else` part. Can anyone help me find what is the issue?

Comment: `if(i>64 && i<91)` doesn't make sense. You should use `if(isalpha(i))` after including `ctype.h` to check if the input is an alphabet. Also, use `if((isdigit(i))` to check if `i` is a number.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: hint: look up an ASCII chart and see what code 10 means

Answer (score 5):

In the first iteration, you type a character and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `scanf` consumes the character you entered, leaving the `\n` in the standard input stream (`stdin`).

In the second iteration, `scanf` sees the `\n` character consumes it, thus not waiting for further input.

You can tell `scanf` to read and discard the next character by using:

```
scanf("%c%*c", &i);
```

or you can tell `scanf` to read and discard all whitespace characters, if any, before reading a character and storing it in `i` by using:

```
scanf(" %c",&i);
/*     ↑ Note the space */
```